# Custom UIButton : how to set background color on selection change?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have created a custom `UIButton` and I want its background to be red when selected, otherwise white.

So I tried this:

```
class MyCustomButton: UIButton {

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = isSelected ? .red : .white
        }
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work, I've set a breakpoint but it never gets called. How can I do so? Thanks

Comment: Have you made sure you actually use a `MyCustomButton` in the interface Builder? Have you ever actually set the `isSelected` property? You know that UIKit does not change that state on its own?

Comment: use setbackgroundcolor  method of uibutton and set state .normal

Comment: Actually Your Code is working. Did you change your `button` class from `UIButton` to `MyCustomButton` in your `UIStoryBoard` or in button `Outlet`?

Comment: `@IBAction func btnStartTapped(_ sender: MyCustomButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected }`

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers, and yes I have already changed my button class in IB. @luk2302 ok but then, how can I catch the state change to update the background color in the custom class?

Comment: @Someday, still button bg is not changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about :

```
override open var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor.red : UIColor.white
    }
}
```

**Note** : The button type should be **custom**. It won't work on button with type system.

Comment: Is the button type set to custom ? If it is system type, it won't work.

Comment: why does this answer use "isHighlighted" instead of "isSelected" ?  I'm working on same problem -- thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing interface builder connection with your button.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but I have already ensured that this is set up correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the background image of the current button.

I hope it will help you.

```
UIButton* customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[[customButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stateNormalImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]];
[[customButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stateSelectedlImage"] forState:UIControlStateSelected]];
```

Comment: Neither is this helpful, nor is this close to compiling since you included the Xcode editor placeholders.

Comment: Stick around buddy!!  That was very brave putting up an answer.

Comment: @BooberBunz THX. But I answered the grammar mistake.

Comment: @luk2302 I'm sorry. It's only recently that it's been in contact.Not so much experience writing the answers.The syntax is bad.

Comment: @luk2302 But I think my approach is right.I also edited the changes here. I hope you understand, thank you for reminding me.